# add a tab programically, c# tab control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

hi everybody
i want to ask :
How to add a tab programmically.

for my problem
i have a tab control, as default only one tab. and i have a button when i click that button will add one other tab. so will be two tab.

please help me using c# and xaml.

Comment: I'd also like to say that like many of us I enjoy sharing my knowledge, helping people and getting helped, but this is not my job, so I'd encourage people asking questions to google a little bit before... TabControl.Items.Add is one of the first things you get to learn if you type something like "TabControl WPF tutorial" with El goog...

Answer (score 6):

```
tabControl.Items.Add(yourNewTabItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Add("tab 3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Some more code to create and modify tabPages manually:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TabControl tc;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tc = new TabControl();

        tc.TabPages.AddRange(new TabPage[]
        {
            new TabPage("tabPage 1"),
            new TabPage("tabPage 2")
        });

        tc.Location = new Point(20, 20);
        tc.Size = new Size(300, 200);
        this.ClientSize = new Size(350, 250);
        this.Controls.Add(tc);

        //renaming:
        this.tc.TabPages[0].Text = "1st tab";
        this.tc.TabPages[1].Text = "2nd tab";

        //changing background:
        this.tc.TabPages[0].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        this.tc.TabPages[1].BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;

        //adding some controls to each tab:
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Location = new Point(20, 20);
        tb.Size = new Size(130, 20);
        tb.Text = "This textBox is on 1st tab";

        Label lb = new Label();
        lb.Location = new Point(20, 20);
        lb.Text = "This label is on 2nd tab";
        lb.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        this.tc.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(tb);
        this.tc.TabPages[1].Controls.Add(lb);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi,i dont know why, tc.TabPages.AddRange() not work, may be i must do something?