# Why do we use itemsource actually?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, itemsource

I am new to .net and i studied on msdn that it "represents a control that can be used to present a collection of items."
By this line what i understand is suppose if i use it for TabControl then it provides a control which will enable several TabItems (collection) to render on the given
conatiner.

```
<controls:TabControl Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0" Background="White" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding TabList, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource TabConverter}}"
```

Could someone please correct (if i am wrong) with an example easy to understand showing why do we use it. What happen if we dont use it?

Comment: What outside "you do not have anything inside the control"?

Comment: `ItemsSource` drives the collection of tabs in the control. It requires an `IEnumerable` typed object. In simple terms the `TabControl` counts the number of objects in the enumerable, spawns a tab for each object, sets the datacontext of the instantiated tab (to the enumerated object) and the binding system does the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `ItemsSource` it so create a dynamic number of tabs depending on some data stored in a class (You need to set the `DataContext` of the `Window` though.

If you don't use `ItemsSource`, you could use separate TabItems to create a static number of tabs.

So it is this (showing a tab for each name in the list):

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfNames}}" />
```

Opposing to:

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem Header="John">
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem Header="Jane">
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem Header="Dave">
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: in my case i have to create number of tabItems that i dont know at start (will be created dynamically by button click) . So the only way to do is ItemSorce ? right ?

Comment: Or in the Window code them by hand. Using a viewmodel and binding is more work to start, but will give you much joy when maintaining it.

Comment: sorry  i couldnt understand . you mean either do statically in xaml ? (but i dont know how many Tabitem user will ad on buttonclick)

Comment: Eventhing you do in XAML will eventually become code. See this answer as example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5487907/993547.

Comment: actual problem was this (thanks if you could answer tehre also) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661264/how-to-update-the-data-to-anothers-view-xaml-from-another-viewmodel-class-mv